# Pasting columns from a dataframe into an external text file?

Tags: r, connection, paste

I have a bunch of files that need data from a dataframe pasted into them. I would like to paste the data frames content so that each column is side by side under the block of pre-existing text in the text file.

The code below formats the dataframe correctly, but I would like to know how I can write it to go between certain lines in the external text file. Not actually as a separate text document called "output.txt".

```
v1 <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6) 
v2 <- c(2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12)

 df <- data.frame(v1, v2)
 write.table(df,  file = "output.txt", row.names = F, col.names = T, sep= "\t     ")
```

Should look something like this:

```
1842,590557.5400513,4737440.08479108,0
1843,590564.76375474,4737440.65162957,0
*End
"v1"         "v2"
1                 2
2                 4
3                 6
4                 8
5                 10
6                 12
```

Comment: Let's say your file is named `data.txt`. You can probably do `write.table(df, file = "data.txt", row.names = F, col.names = T, sep = "\t", append = TRUE)`

Comment: Indeed! Thanks. However, if it were to be appended between, for example, a given set of rows like #20 and 21?

Comment: Append doesn't have a location parameter, I think the best way would probably be to read the text file, split it into two parts based on the row, insert your data frame, and then put it back together.